# Why is this PHP form submitting when required data is missing?

Tags: php, forms

Here is a form I created. I want all the input fields to be required. However when I just select one of the checkboxes it returns the printed validation message when it should be returning the error message. If I leave the check boxes empty it returns an error message. I'm new to PHP and wondering why the checkboxes in my code are validating the whole form when they should be giving an error message if the other input fields are left blank.

```
<?php

// Check for form submission:
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

//minimal form validation:
if (isset($_POST['food_quality'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['comment'])){


// Print out message
echo '<p>Thank you <b>' . $_POST['name'] . '</b> for filling out this form. We will 
contact you at <b>' . $_POST['email'] . ' </b>in regards to the following food rating of 
<b>' . $_POST['food_quality'] .'</b> and your comments:<br /> <b>' . $_POST['comment'] 
.'</b></br /> <br /> Have a great day!</p>';

    } else { // Invalid submitted values.
        echo '<h1>Error!</h1> <p class="error">Please ender a valid information!</p>';
    } 
}

//Leave PHP and create HTML form

?>

<h1> Bob's Bar and Grill Feedback form:</h1>

<form action="feedback.php" method="post">

<p>Name:<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['name'])){ echo 
$_POST['name'];} ?>" /><br /> Email:<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php 
if(isset($_POST['email'])){ echo $_POST['email'];}?>" /><br />
</p>

<p>The food was:</p>    
<p><input type="checkbox" name="food_quality" value="excellent" 
<?php if(isset($_POST['food_quality']) && ($_POST['food_quality'] == 'excellent') ) {echo 
'checked="checked"';}?> /> excellent!
<input type="checkbox" name="food_quality" value="okay"
<?php if(isset($_POST['food_quality']) && ($_POST['food_quality'] == 'okay')) {echo 
'checked="checked"';}?> /> okay
<input type="checkbox" name="food_quality" value="poor"
<?php if(isset($_POST['food_quality']) && ($_POST['food_quality'] == 'poor')) {echo 
'checked="checked"';}?> /> poor <br /> </p> 
<p>Comments:<br />
<textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40" ><?php if(isset($_POST['comment'])){echo 
$_POST['comment'];}?></textarea></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p>

</form>
```

Comment: On a side note, your form is vulnerable to XSS. You should use encode your attributes using `htmlspecialchars`. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253237/dealing-with-htmlescape-htmlspecialchars

Answer (score 1):

You are using [`isset`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to determine if data had been sent to the form. `isset` checks if a variable is `NULL`, but your form will send empty string values. You will need to check if each value is [`empty`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

In example, replace

```
if (isset($_POST['food_quality'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['comment'])){
```

with

```
if (isset($_POST['food_quality'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['comment'])
    && !empty($_POST['food_quality'])
    && !empty($_POST['name'])
    && !empty($_POST['email'])
    && !empty($_POST['comment'])
){
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the variables are set. Empty, but set.

You need to check if they are set and not [empty](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

For checkboxes, no variable is set if unchecked. If you want to send them too, create a hidden field before the checkbox with the same name. That would be de default value for unchecked checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Since the values are in your form, they are set, no matter if they are empty or not.  Instead of `isset()`, use `!empty()`. (The `!` makes it so that it returns true if it has data, false if empty.

Answer (score 0):

You have called all checkbox with same name, so all checkboxes references to the same name. This is an error, you need to assign different names to differente checkboxes (this is the opposite of radios input).

Also it is better to check if $_POST['xxx'] is also true (as Alexander says)